# Show that $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} f(z)=0$ in |z|>1 where f is holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis

If f is holomorphic function in |z|>1 such that $ \lim\limits_{z \to \infty} \frac{Re(f(z))}{z} =0 $ show that $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} f(z)=0$.

When I first tried this question, I thought about Schwartz's Lemma, in which defines $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}$ in |z|<1. Then when I thought it more carefully, they don't seem to be related.

Since $ \lim\limits_{z \to \infty} \frac{Re(f(z))}{z} =0 $, we know that $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} Re(f(z))<\infty.$ But how to show that the limit of f(z) exits and equals to 0?

Could anyone help me or tell me if I am totally wrong and should take a look some other ways?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try $f(z)=1$ for all $z$.

Comment: Did you mean $\lim_{z\to \infty} f(z)/z = 0?$